# Is there such a thing as function decomposability?

Tags: analysis, functions, terminology

I am not a mathematician, so what I ask might be trivial, however I couldn't find something relevant in the web. My question is the following:

Is there a formal notation for functions that comply the following

$$f(x_1, ..., x_n) = g(f(x_1), ..., g(f(x_n))$$

and if there is such a property, how is it called? The current, intuitive name I can think of is decomposable functions, but I don't know if formally there is such a thing.

**Example 1:** An additive function would be decomposable.

**Example 2:** A multiplicative function would also be decomposable

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 1):

I think the notion of [homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra#Basic_constructions) in universal algebra might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any standard terminology for this property.  I think "decomposability" is a fine term when defined in context.  An interesting example of such a function is $f(f(x)) = x^2+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Multivariate functions representable as a combination of univariate functions arise in several places in mathematics. For instance, ordinary differential equations $y'(x) = f(x,y)$ where $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ are called equations with *separable* variables. Such equations can be easily solved by integrating $G(x)=\int g(x)dx$ and $F(y)=\int\frac{dy}{h(y)}$ separately, and solving the equation $F(y)=G(x)$ for $y$.

Also a method of *separation of variables* for solving homogeneous partial differential equations in two variables is based on searching for a solution in the form of a product of univariate functions. For instance for Laplace equation $\Delta u = 0$ considering a solution of the form $u(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ leads to a pair of ordinary differential equations and ultimately to a method of finding a solution to boundary value problems for Laplace equation in the form of a series $u(x,y) = \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty B_n g_n(x)h_n(y)$ where $g_n(x)$ and $h_n(y)$ are the functions corresponding to the $n$-th eigenvalue of the boundary value problem.

A special case where a multivariate function $f(x,y_1,...,y_k)$ is a linear combination of the form $\Sigma_{i=1}^n g_i(x)h_i(y_1,...,y_k)$, is of special interest. Such functions had been called *decomposable* in the literature (cf. M. Čadek, J. Šimša, [Decomposable functions of several variables](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02112277), Aequationes Mathematicae, 1990, and references thereof).

For sufficiently differentiable functions there is an easy test of decomposability. Consider a function of two variables $f(x,y)$. Define its *Wronskian* as

$\mathcal{W}_n=\mathop{\textrm{det}}\left[\frac{\partial^{i+j}f}{\partial x^i\partial y^j}\right].$

*Note that this differs from the usual definition of Wronskian of a sequence of univariate functions. This is can be seen as a usual Wronskian with respect to the first variable of the sequence of partial derivatives in the second variable.*

We can say that a sufficiently differentiable function $f(x,y)$ is decomposable as $f(x,y)=\Sigma_{i=1}^n g_i(x)h_i(y)$ for some $n$ if and only if $\mathcal{W}_n = 0$ and $\mathcal{W}_{n-1} \neq 0$.

Getting back to the original question of naming, the word *decomposable* is alright and has been used in the literature, however variants on the theme of *separation of variables* or *separability* might fit in some contexts.